How to find the vertices of an equilateral triangle given one other vertex and the lines on which the vertices must lie
A square in the argand plane has vertices $5+5i$, $5-5i$, $-5-5i$, $-5+5i$. The complex number $z_a=5+i$, $z_b$, and $z_c$ lie on the square and form the vertices of an equilateral triangle. Find the exact value of $z_b$. I have scoured all corners of the internet including ChatGPT, and nothing has provided an answer or method for answer that satisfies the requirements.


For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

What have you tried? Where did you have trouble in the solution? If we know this, it will be easier for us to help you out.

I have tried a lot of things, to the point where it is not really relevant what I have done. I'm having trouble in actually knowing what to do. I could probably figure it out if the centre of the triangle was known, but as far as I can tell the given information isn't enough to figure out that out. Any suggestions on what to do, or solutions that you can show fulfil the requirements are welcome and wanted. I don't care if it is a method I've tried or not, that's besides the point for me.

Firstly $z_b$ would be of the form $x_1+5i$ and $z_c$ would be of the form $x_2-5i$. Use these two identities which hold true for an equilateral triangle with vertices $z_1,z_2,z_3$:
$z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 = z_1 z_2 + z_2 z_3 + z_3 z_1$
and
$|z_1-z_2|=|z_3-z_1|=|z_2-z_3|$ and you can also notice two right angled triangles with vertices ($x_1+5i$, $5+5i$ and $5+i$) and ($x_2-5i$, $5+i$ and $5-5i$) respectively ,  you can also apply Pythagoras theorem in these two triangles, i think this information will solve the question

@SjaakAnkersmit you say "I don't care if it is a method I've tried or not", but we don't know what you've tried. It's hard to provide any guidance without that (it's only really possible to just give a solution, but generally people don't want to do that without seeing you've attempted something first).

If you're completely stuck on where to start, I would suggest just listing some basic things you know about equilateral triangles. Then list the information you know from the question, and what other information you would need to have a solution. You want to write down equations that describe the triangle using the information you have and the unknowns. As mentioned earlier, you already know the imaginary parts of $z_B$ and $z_C$, so two of your unknowns are the corresponding real parts. Is there something else you would ideally like to know that would help describe the triangle?

If we have a triangle in the Argand plane the length and direction of sides
can be represented by complex numbers.  For the example triangle the sides
going out from $Z_C$ are $Z_B-Z_C$ and $Z_A -Z_C$.  In a triangle to
get from a complex number the represents the side away from a vertex to another
side away from the same vertex,  we have a scaling and rotation represented by another complex numbers.   Let us call that rotation and scaling $f$.  We have
\begin{equation}
 Z_B -Z_C = f \cdot \left(  Z_A -Z_C \right)
\end{equation}
The factor $f$ will depend only on the relative lengths of the two sides and on the angle bewteen the two sides.  Now for an equilateral triangle all sides are the same length, and the angle is always 60 degrees.   If we let $Z_C$ be at the origin and $Z_A$ at  1,  we can put $Z_B$  at the right position so that we get a equilateral triangle.  It must have a real value of 1/2, because symmetric.   The hypotenuse has a length of 1,  so we can use the pythagorian theorem to get a height of $ \sqrt{3}/2  $. (In general we use the sine of the angle, here 60 degrees.)  So we have plugging into the previous equation
\begin{equation}
\left(\left(1/2+  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right)  - 0 \right) = f  \cdot  \left( \left( 1 \right) - 0 \right)
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
f = \left( \frac {1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i\right)  
\end{equation}
The  complex number  $f$ is just a rotation of 60 degrees.  If you squared it you would get a rotation of 120 degrees.
Now in the first equations we can write $Z_b$ as $X_B + Y_B i$ and $Z_C$ as $X_C + Y_C i$.    This one equation can be split into two real equations with two unknowns,  one for real values and the other for imaginary parts.   Now we can directly solve for  $X_C$ in the equation from imaginary part since $X_B$ does not appear. All the other variables are known.  Then plug back $X_B$ into the equation with real parts and solve for $X_C$.
The first equation for the real part is
\begin{equation}
x_b -x_c = (x_a-x_c) \frac{1}{2}  - (y_a-y_c)  \frac{\sqrt {3 }}  {2}
\end{equation}
Note in the real equation we have imaginary parts of $Z_A$ and $Z_C$.
That is because they are multiplied by imaginary part of $f$ which gives a real.
The second equation for the imaginary part is:
\begin{equation}
y_b - y_c = (x_a -x_c)  \frac{\sqrt3}{2} + (y_a - y_c) \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Solving for $x_c$ in the second I get  $5- \frac {14}{\sqrt{3}}$,  which looks ok.
Finally, plugging $x_c$ back into the real part equation we have:
\begin{equation}
x_b = 5 - \frac{7}{\sqrt{3}} - 3 \sqrt{3}
\end{equation}

I've done as you suggested, solving $z_B=z_A+f⋅(z_B-z_A)+f⋅(z_A-[z_A+f⋅(z_B-z_A)])$ where $f=1/2+\sqrt3/2i$, $z_A=5+i$, and $z_B=x_B+5i$. In doing this, I've gotten a sizeable equation for $z_B$, but it still contains $x_B$ (being $Re(z_B)$). Obviously this is what I need to solve for, but I'm not sure how to. Have I done something wrong in the substitution, or otherwise how should I proceed from there? I have tried solving $Im(z_B)=5i=(8-4\sqrt3-3x_B+\sqrt3x_B)/4$ for $x_B$, but that gave me $-8-4\sqrt3$, which $\approx-14.93$, which isn't on the square. What would you do?

I redid answer because of your first comment and found I had a mistake.  You only need one equation (which splis into two because of real and imaginary parts)!  Sorry for the misdirection.  I have redone the answer.  (I realized the two equations are not independent,  so leads to confusing results.)  Let me read what you wrote more carefully and see if I have something else t say.

Looking at your math.  Following my previous bad advice,  you should get the $z_B$ cancels out.  That is because $f-f^2 = 1$, so have  $Z_B$ on both sides of equations.  When I did that is when I realized I made mistake using two dependent equations. So the problem wasn't the equation was too complicated - it is too simple.  $Z_B$ goes away!

Thanks for your help, but I ended up solving it using a different method. Formula was $$\frac{z_B-z_C}{z_A-z_C}=\frac{|z_B-z_C|}{|z_A-z_C|}e^{i\theta}$$ where $z_B=x_B+5i$, $z_C=x_C-5i$, and $\theta=60°=\frac{π}{3}$. Since the triangle is equilateral, the right-hand-side fraction = 1 ($\because$ it's two side lengths which are equal divided). Convert $e^{i\theta}$ into $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, multiply the bottom of the left fraction across, and group Re and Im. Take Im and solve for $x_C$, and substitute into Re to solve for $x_B$ as required.

Nice you got.  Basically the same method.  Your right hand side is $f$.  Solve for $x_C$, then and plug back for $X_B$ just as answer I gave.  The key understanding is ratio of sides of triangle can be represented by complex numbers.  The ratio consists of a scale and rotation,  as in your right hand side.
